# display locale in url rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localization, url-routing

I have applied the localization in my website, it is working fine but I am facing to main issue in this.

1. I want to display the local in url, I did not find way to do it
2. I want to get the browser langauge and set locale to it (I know this for developement envirnoment but not production)

P.S. everything I am taking in production envirnoment

Here is how I have added localization

application controller

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
 if cookies[:educator_locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym)
  l = cookies[:educator_locale].to_sym
 else
  cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
  end
  I18n.locale = l
 end
```

My settings controller

```
 def change_locale
l = params[:locale].to_s.strip.to_sym
l = I18n.default_locale unless I18n.available_locales.include?(l)
cookies.permanent[:educator_locale] = l
redirect_to request.referer
 end
```

My view

```
   <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
    <li> <%= link_to image_tag("france.png", :style => "center"), change_locale_path(:fr) %></li>
    <% else %>
    <li>          <%= link_to image_tag("usa.png", :align => "center"), change_locale_path(:en)%></li>
    <% end %>
```

and finally my routes

```
 get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
 get "home/index"
```

To get browser language I was using this [browser link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-client-supplied-information) but it is only for developement[1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-client-supplied-information)

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Simple locale switcher blog post](http://www.active-bridge.com/2015/02/20/rails-locale-switcher/). It should help

Comment: But, the issue I mentioned is not addressed on this link, it is just simple implementation of localization which I already done..